# create new columns derived from existing columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to split 1 column value into 3 columns.

```
df['Campaign name']
0     US_FEMALE_20to30
1        US_MIX_35to45
2     US_FEMALE_20to30
3        US_MIX_35to45
4       US_MALE_30to35
5        US_MIX_35to45
```

so in the end, it will look like that

```
   region   gender   age
0   US      FEMALE   20to30
1   US      MIX      35to45
2   US      FEMALE   20to30
3   US      MIX      35to45
4   US      MALE     30to35
5   US      MIX      35to45
```

thanks a lot

Comment: use: `out=df['Campaign name'].str.split('_',expand=True)` after that rename columns `out.columns=['region','gender','age']` now if you print out you will get your output see the documentation of [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the str.split function.

In str.split, you use

1. specify the delimiter in quotes
2. the 'n' parameter to specify how many times you want to split
3. Use 'expand' parameter to expand the columns into new columns

Then you create those columns in df as shown below

```
# new data frame with split value columns
new = df["Campaign_name"].str.split("_", n = 2, expand = True)
  
# making separate columns from new data frame
df["region"]= new[0]
df["gender"]= new[1]
df["age"]= new[2]
```

Output using df.head()

```
    Campaign_name     region    gender   age
0   US_FEMALE_20to30    US      FEMALE   20to30
1   US_MIX_35to45       US      MIX      35to45
2   US_FEMALE_20to30    US      FEMALE   20to30
3   US_MIX_35to45       US      MIX      35to45
4   US_MALE_30to35      US      MALE     30to35
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with named groups is also a nice alternative:

```
df['Campaign name'].str.extract('(?P<region>.*)_(?P<gender>.*)_(?P<age>.*)')
```

output:

```
  region  gender     age
0     US  FEMALE  20to30
1     US     MIX  35to45
2     US  FEMALE  20to30
3     US     MIX  35to45
4     US    MALE  30to35
5     US     MIX  35to45
```